# sensors lastMeasurementTime

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've configured a robot with 2 laser scanners and a IMU
all the sensors have 10Hz update rate

now, If I look at sensor datas I notice that datas have different time stamp:
e.g. by using gztopic echo, IMU time stamps are 0.1, 0.2 and so on
the first laser produces data at 0.101, 0.201, 0.301 and so on
and the second laser at 0.102, 0.202, 0.203

notice that my simulation time is 1ms, so exactly the 0.001 differences between sensors

it is that normal? why this happens?
I was expecting that all the sensors were acquired exactly at the same time since they have the same update rate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1652/sensors-lastmeasurementtime/) by [SImone](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/207/simone/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sensor and physics run in different threads. It's possible for physics to take a step between an IMU and Laser update.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0